# Editing Data From a Domain Service

Tags: silverlight

I need to edit data in a WCF RIA Domain Service. all examples I can find are using a datagrid.
I have the following but it is retuning a null value, where am I going wrong???

```
var mytask = from v in  DomainRentDetail.tblRentDetails 

where v.CustID == xCustID 
select v; 

tblRentDetail t = mytask.FirstOrDefault<tblRentDetail>(); 
t.ReturnDate = DateTime.Now; 

DomainRentDetail.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please give us more detail but,
I think it must be like this, In a domain service class (I suppose you are on web project)

```
 from v in  this.ObjectContext.tblRentDetails 
 where v.....
 select v
```

If there are some records on your table **tblRentDetails**

you may check it by FirstOrDefault << Type >> ()== null

When you create your domain service class you must choose your domain(edmx). Then ObjectContext carries your entitiy objects. Ask your Entities to this ObjectContext member.

Note: The below state is an extreme stuation. Maybe you may face off laterly.

If you need diffrent model you are not created domain service class for
there are some other technics,

```
//Scope level domain service class definition. Not offered.
//Generally views solves this issue
using(XDomainService service=new XDomainService())
{
  from one in service 
  from two in this.objectContext
  where...
  select new member
}
```